# How to handle a double click on selected row in SwiftUI on macOS App?

Tags: macos, swiftui, tableview

I want to handle a double click on a table.

Here's my code

```
         Table(transactions, selection: $selectedTransactions) {
                
                TableColumn("Date") { transaction in
                    Text(transaction.transactionDate, formatter: dateFormatter)
                        .foregroundColor(transaction.transactionStatus.statusColor)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded{
                            print("double click")
                        })
                }
}
```

For now I can handle a double click on my cell. But I want only handle a double click on the selected row and I don't want to repeat myself on each column.

Any idea, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var transactions = [
        Transaction(date: "Jan 01", status: .pending),
        Transaction(date: "Jan 02", status: .completed),
        Transaction(date: "Jan 03", status: .failed),
        Transaction(date: "Jan 04", status: .pending),
        Transaction(date: "Jan 05", status: .completed),
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedTransactions = Set<Transaction.ID>()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(transactions, selection: $selectedTransactions) {
            TableColumn("Date") { transaction in
                Text(transaction.date)
                    .foregroundColor(transaction.status.statusColor)
            }
            // TableColumn("Status", value: \.status.rawValue) // Optional second column
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            print(selectedTransactions)
        }
    }
}

struct Transaction {
    var date: String
    var status: TransactionStatus
    
    enum TransactionStatus: String {
        case pending
        case completed
        case failed
        
        var statusColor: Color {
            switch self {
            case .pending:
                return .orange
            case .completed:
                return .green
            case .failed:
                return .red
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Transaction: Identifiable {
    var id: String { date }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @PaulB but nothing is print on the console with your code. I use a Xcode 14 on macOS Ventura. I just create a macOS app and copy / past your code...

Comment: This is quite unexpected. I've checked on iOS 16 simulator in Xcode 14.0.1 (14A400). It prints ["Jan 04"], ["Jan 03"], etc. when row is double-clicked.

Comment: I change the tag and title of my question with macOS

Comment: Good, now it is clear that issue is macOS related.